# The equation $\sin x+x\cos x=0$ has atleast one root in

Tags: calculus

The equation $\sin x+x\cos x=0$ has atleast one root in 
$(A)(\frac{-\pi}{2},0)$
$(B)(0,\pi)$
$(C)(\pi,\frac{3\pi}{2})$
$(D)(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$

---

I tried to use the property that if $f(a)f(b)<0$,then $f(x)$ has atleast one root in $(a,b)$,but this property is not working here.
 
What should i do?

Comment: Why isn't it working? $f(\pi/2)=1,f(\pi)=-\pi$. So (B) is certainly correct, and that is all you need. Note that you don't have to pick $a,b$ as the *endpoints* of the interval. It is enough that they be inside the interval where you want to find a root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $x=0$ you get a root so for your $a$ and $b$ in those situations you want to use a value slightly away from this number. E.g. test (A) $(-\frac{\pi}{2},-0.001)$, (B) $(0.001,\pi)$, (C) as is, (D) $(0.001,\frac{\pi}{2})$. This will show you that (B) has a solution as subbing in $x=0.001$ gives a positive value where as subbing in $x=\pi$ gives a negative value.

Note: The test you are using will fail if there are two (or any even number) of roots in the domain.

Comment: Yes i know that this test will fail in case of two roots.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that this is equivalent to writing $\tan x = -x$, and their intersection can be shown graphically:

[image]

This shows there's an intersection at a little more than $x = 1.6$.  Answer choice B seems reasonable.

Comment: I think your approach is  correct, however this does not provide a systematic proof  for the answer.  By the way, one may simply plot the fucntion and seee its roots http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin%28x%29%2Bxcos%28x%29 .

Comment: @Nizar You're certainly correct, and I agree with you.  To be fair though, the OP did not specify what method would be acceptable for determining the solution.  Seeing how it's multiple choice, a graphical approach seems far-fetched.  I'll remove my answer if they deem it unacceptable.

Comment: @Mnifldz Your solution may help others reading this question so definitely leave it. As I mentioned the test the OP used has only limited application.